# YouTube Iframe API Embed with No Ads on Video

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

In my project, I am using YouTube video embeds (not my videos) and I want them to not display ads.

When I use Iframe embed (without Iframe API - with youtube-nocookie.com), it works, ads are not displayed, which I want.

```
<iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/7TXKBlBBbIA?fs=0&modestbranding=1&playsinline=1&rel=0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But when I use Iframe API (with youtube-nocookie.com), ads are displayed, which I don't want.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

```
// HTML
<div id="video"></div>

// JS
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    video = new YT.Player('video', {
        height: 360,
        width: 640,
        videoId: '7TXKBlBBbIA',
        host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
        playerVars: {
            'fs': 0,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'playsinline': 1,
            'rel': 0
        }
    });
}
```

The thing is, I need to use the Iframe API, but not display ads. Any way to achieve that?

It seems `https://listenonrepeat.com/` does it, but I couldn't figure out how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Turn ads on or off on embedded videos**
If you've associated your YouTube and AdSense accounts and have allowed embedding videos, you'll automatically be opted into showing ads. Note that embedded videos will honor the same ad enablement settings as videos on youtube.com.

If you don't want to show ads on your embedded videos, there's no way to directly turn off ads on embedded videos only. You may turn off embedding altogether.

Checkout [YouTube Support Page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en)

As you mentioned, it might be possible that developers at https://listenonrepeat.com/ get rights from the content creator and upload those videos in their channel or it may also be possible that all the videos that are played by https://listenonrepeat.com/ are not monetized by the content creator.

Comment: Thanks. But as mentioned in the question, when I use iframe embed directly (without API), ads are not displayed. I am trying to achieve the same with the API, that is, if it is possible.

Comment: Not always, Even I had embedded an iframe in my blog but, it did have ads sometimes

Comment: That site is using Iframe API, and they are embedding YouTube videos. Videos I tested show ads on my setup, but not on their site.

Comment: Did you try `host: youtube.com` instead of `youtube-nocookie.com`?

Comment: Just tested again. It displayed ads.

Comment: Actually, I think https://listenonrepeat.com/ **may** have partnerships with YouTube and YouTube **may** have provided them with some access keys or so... But, I am not sure.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for your input, appreciated.